# How to duplicate desktop file on applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm trying to duplicate my desktop file on apple script using script editor but I can't figure out how to do it. Can someone please help me?

Comment: What do you mean by your "desktop file"? Do you mean a file that's on your desktop, the `~/Desktop` directory, or something else entirely?

Comment: I mean everything on my desktop the desktop file in finder

Comment: It's not explicitly and specifically clear what it is you're trying to code, however I've tried to cover the bases in my answer. If my answer doesn't get you want you're looking for then you'll need to edit your question. Have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The following *command* will *duplicate* your **Desktop** *folder* in **Finder** as **Desktop copy** and will be in your **Home** *folder*:

```
tell application "Finder" to duplicate desktop
```

---

The following *commands* will *duplicate* the *target object* directly on the **Desktop**, i.e., objects within the **Desktop** *folder* in your **Home** *folder* in **Finder** .

The following *command* will *duplicate* every *file* on your **Desktop**:

```
tell application "Finder" to duplicate every file of desktop
```

The following *command* will *duplicate* every *folder* on your **Desktop**:

```
tell application "Finder" to duplicate every folder of (path to desktop)
```

The following *command* will *duplicate* every *file* and *folder* on your **Desktop**:

```
tell application "Finder" to duplicate every item of (path to desktop)
```

---

**NOTES:**

This is to address the comment made by [has](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7813536/has):

As to: "1. You don’t need path to desktop as Finder’s application object already has a desktop property containing a reference to the user’s Desktop."

This is not categorically a true statement and depends on how it's being used. It's true with the **Desktop** *folder* itself and *files* within the **Desktop** *folder*, **however** it is **absolutely false** with `duplicate every folder of` and `duplicate every item of`, and without using `(path to desktop)` in these instances it errors out with the following *error statement*:

```
"Finder got an error: The folder “” can’t be moved into itself." number -122
```

As to: "2. Never do duplicate every item of desktop – if the Finder’s preferences are set to display mounted volumes on the Desktop then those will be included too, and you definitely don’t want to duplicate those!"

**That statement is categorically false!**

He/she ([has](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7813536/has)) obviously doesn't know what he/she is talking about because mounted volumes are not located within the **Desktop** *folder* in your **Home** *folder*. By default, they are mounted at `/Volumes` and while they can appear on **the Desktop**, they are not directly connected to the **Desktop** *folder* in your **Home** *folder*.

In this reference **the Desktop** and **Desktop** *folder* in your **Home** *folder* are not the same thing!

Comment: 1. You don’t need `path to desktop` as Finder’s `application` object already has a `desktop` property containing a reference to the user’s Desktop. 2. Never do `duplicate every item of desktop` – if the Finder’s preferences are set to display mounted volumes on the Desktop then those will be included too, and you definitely don’t want to duplicate those!

Comment: Whomever up voted has's comment is as misinformed as he/she is! Read the **NOTES:** section in my answer.